# How to filter a joined child table in EF Core 6 using the 'where' clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to write a code by EF Core which yields the following sql.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Shops
JOIN Products P ON Shops.Id = P.ShopId
WHERE Shops.Id = 1 AND P.IsDeleted = 0;
```

My `Shops` model is

```cs
public class Shop
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;

    public IList<PaymentMethod> PaymentMethods { get; set; } = default!;
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserShop> ApplicationUserShops { get; set; } = default!;
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

and my `Products` model is

```cs
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
    public Shop Shop { get; set; } = default!;
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
}
```

My temporal LINQ code is

```
public async Task<Shop?> GetShopWithProductsByIdAsync(int id)
{
    return await _context.Shops
                         .Include(s => s.Products.Where(p => !p.IsDeleted))
                         .FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
}
```

However, the above code does not filter deleted columns.

How can I get the first SQL?

The full code is [here](https://github.com/phasetr/ASP.NET-Core/tree/main/EFCoreQuestionSO20230315/EFCoreQuestionSO20230315).

**Edited**: Thanks to jdweng, I can write my desired code:

```cs
public async Task<Shop?> GetShopWithProductsByIdAsync(int id)
{
    return await _context.Shops
        .Join(_context.Products.Where(p => !p.IsDeleted),
            s => s.Id,
            p => p.ShopId,
            (s, p) => new {s, p})
        .GroupBy(x => x.s)
        .Select(x => new Shop
        {
            Id = x.Key.Id,
            Name = x.Key.Name,
            Products = x.Select(y => y.p).ToList()
        })
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code will look something like this

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Context context = new Context();
            var results = from s in context.Shop.Where(x => x.Id == 1)
                           join p in context.Product.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false) on s.Id equals p.Id
                           select new {s = s, p = p};

 
 
        }
    }
    public class Context
    {
        public List<Shop> Shop { get;set;}
        public List<Product> Product { get;set;}
    }
    public class Shop
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = default!;

        //public IList<PaymentMethod> PaymentMethods { get; set; } = default!;
        //public ICollection<ApplicationUserShop> ApplicationUserShops { get; set; } = default!;
        public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } = default!;
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int ShopId { get; set; }
        public Shop Shop { get; set; } = default!;
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, and I can get the data `IQueryable<Shop,Product>`!

I have one more question: can I get the data with the form `Shop` (or `Task<Shop>`), and `Shop.Products` the filtered product list? This is my original motivation. Of course I can get it by the following code.

```
var shop = _context.Shops.Include(s => s.Products).First(m => m.Id == 1);
shop.Products = shop.Products.Where(p => !p.IsDeleted).ToList();
```

Can I get this by one LINQ chain?

Comment: You can modify the NEW in my query to combine the two lists (S & P) any way you like.  I sometimes add parentheses around the query to group items (from ....).GroupBy(x => x.s.ID).

Comment: Thank you for your comment! You can solve my problem! I added the code I wrote in the post.